# Is there a way to invite an app user's friend to a Facebook event?

Tags: facebook

Well, everything is in the title: I want to invite user's friends to a Facebook event via an app. I've seen that it is not possible with the 2.1 Graph API but maybe there is another way?

Comment: Let your users send a message to their friends, and include the link to the event page …?

Comment: Yes, I think I'll do that, thanks for the idea !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/event/invited

> You cannot invite people to events via the Graph API.

There is no other way with the API.